# Why do Passover and Unleavened Bread last 9-days?

Tags: passover

In Scripture the requirement is to observe Passover on 14 Nissan (1-day) and Unleavened Bread on 15 Nissan through 21 Nissan (7-days). What is the basis for the [9-day period](https://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/871715/jewish/Passover-2019-Pesach.htm)?

Comment: Only eight days; Jewish days go from sunset to sunset. It’s April 19 after nightfall, not the entire April 19. And Chabad there say that it’s only eight days outside of Israel.

Comment: In addition to what DonielF wrote, confusion can also come from the requirement not to eat or own leaven after late morning of April 19 and not to resume eating leaven until late in the evening of April 27 (usually at least 30 minutes after the end of the holiday), about 8 1/2 days.

Comment: @DonielF The day begins at sunset and April 19 after nightfall is 15 Nissan?

Comment: @RevelationLad Yes.

Comment: @Dennis Is the "extension" to make 8 1/2 days a custom? Because from Daniel I see the period as coming to 7 "plus" days (i.e 7 1/2 but not more than 8).

Comment: No, halacha.  Outside Israel, we celebrate an additional day for holidays like Pesach.  Also, the restrictions on eating and owning chometz starts late morning on the 14th of Nisan.